# Unexpected output in a test case of program

Tags: c++, loops, logic, nested-loops

THE code works for all the test cases except this test case. Any idea where it went wrong?

qn:
write down the following sequence of numbers: firstly all odd integers from 1 to n (in ascending order), then all even integers from 1 to n (also in ascending order).to find out which number will stand at the position number k.

---

```
#include <iostream>
 
using namespace std;
 
int main()
{
    int n,k,a;
    cin >> n >> k;
    if(n%2==0){
        if(k<=n/2){
            a = 2*k-1;
        }
        else{
            a = 2*k-n;
        }
    }
    else{
        if(k<=(n/2 + 1)){
            a = 2*k -1;
        }
        else{
            a=2*(k-(n/2 + 1));
        }
    }
    cout << a;
    return 0;
}
```

the wrong test case image is given below, the ans should have been 2 but it says 15
[image]

Comment: The input numbers are too large for `int` type. Try `long long`.

Comment: Do not post text as image. You should copy paste Input as a text.

Comment: ***Any idea where it went wrong?*** Remember on many systems an int is 32 bits and has a range of -2,147,483,648 to 2,147,483,647. Your data is larger than an int can hold.

Comment: https://godbolt.org/z/KGPM8b

Comment: If you apply a little maths, you willf find `auto limit = n/2 + n%2; cout << k <= limit ? 2*k-1 : 2*(k - limit);`

Comment: i have changed int to long long it works now , thank you guys